# Vaadin 12 + Gradle 5 Create executable Fat jar

Tags: java, gradle, vaadin

I need to use Jetty and Vaadin and build a fat jar.

My workspace is based around Gradle 5, Its a gradle multi module project

```
Parent
  Common-Lib
  Core-Lib
  Jetty+Vaadin
```

I followed the documentation which i found here:

https://vaadin.com/tutorials/embedded-jetty-server-in-vaadin-flow

The documentation explains how to create Jetty's WebAppContext and start Jetty Server instance all based around maven.

Expect as i said my workspace is based around gradle, so instead of copying the pom.xml i rewrote it to the gradle build script which looks as follows:

```
plugins {
    id 'idea'
}

group = 'some.example.jetty.and.vaadin.fatjar'
version = '1.0.0'

dependencies {
    implementation project(':Core-Lib')
    implementation project(':Common-Lib')

    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'

    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty', name: 'jetty-continuation', version: '9.4.14.v20181114'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket', name: 'websocket-server', version: '9.4.14.v20181114'
    compile group: 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket', name: 'javax-websocket-server-impl', version: '9.4.14.v20181114'

    compile group: 'com.vaadin', name: 'vaadin-core', version: '12.0.7'
}
```

My problem is that during the build gradle outputs a .war file. I cannot use a .war file.

This project is supposed to be a plug-in module for another application, which i do not have sources for. The application just loads a jar files from specific folder, only jar extension is supported.

My question is: How can i create standard "unshaded" uber jar/fat jar instead of .war

With the word "unshaded" i want to unpack all JAR dependencies, and repack them into the final JAR.

Comment: Are pulling some plugins and is that why it ends up as a war?  E.g. when using springboot + older vaadin gradle plugin you ended up with a .war file, that was both a war and an uberjar.